# How to save google cloud object-tracking video?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, object-detection, video-intelligence-api

Currently working my way through the google cloud video intelligence API -tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/object-tracking

The output gives me details on the bounding boxes, however, it does not actually save any video with the bounding boxes draw on. I'm curious if anyone knows how I would go about drawing the bounding boxes onto my video?